# How can I execute parellely a function on each element of a list and collect the status of the function call?

Tags: java

I have a list of Strings in Java. I have a function that takes as input a string and calls calls some unstable web service (so it is quite possible that an exception can be thrown). If no exceptions are thrown, the function returns two numbers.

What I would like to do is the following: I want to apply in parallel the function to the list, and I want to sum all the pairs of numbers returned by the invocations that succeeded. If all the invocation throw exception, throw exception from the main thread.

Any idea where to start from? I am new to Java 8. I have given a look at `parallelStream` and lambdas, but did not find how to implement this particular situation.

Comment: add more details to your problem, your example code and what you've attempted in code

Comment: From what you're describing, this is not a simple question.  You're asking us to design and implement a complete application.  To get you started look into creating multiple Runnable object and submitting them to a ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: What is the signature for calling the web service? AND: Do you expect the list of strings to be long - even if it is a corner case? Or are you safe to assume that it contains "a few" elements?

Comment: Take a look at executors and futures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) is a good API to use for this purpose.

The following example is more of a pseudocode, than acually working code, because you didn't provide much information. But it should be a good hint on how to use `CompletableFuture` for what you need.

If you have a function that calculates the numbers from the web service, that looks like this:

```
public Pair<Integer, Integer> getThatNumbers(String parameter) {
   //call a REST service, or do some calculation here
}
```

You could use `CompletableFuture` like this:

```
public Pair<Integer, Integer> calculateSum(List<String> parameters) {
    List<CompletableFuture<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    //create the completable futures, that call the service and store them in a list
    for (String param : parameters) {
        futures.add(//
            // create a CompletableFuture that calls the calculation method
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getThatNumbers(param))//use supplyAsync to run the future parallel to the current thread
            .orTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)//a timeout might be usefull when a web service is not responding
            .exceptionally(throwable -> new Pair(0, 0)));//add a fallback, that is used if an exception occurs (and maybe count the failed services, so you know whether there was any that succeeded)
    }

    //use the first CompletableFuture in the list to gather the result (you could use any CompletableFuture here)
    CompletableFuture<Pair<Integer, Integer>> result = futures.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < futures.size(); i++) {
        //combine the results by summing them up
        result.thenCombine(futures.get(i), (result1, result2) -> new Pair(result1.key + result2.key, result1.value + result2.value));
    }

    //wait for all services to finish and get the result
    //the service calls will all be done parallel
    //the get() method will pause the execution here and wait till all CompletableFutures have finished their calculation
    Pair<Integer, Integer> sum = result.get();

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have given a look at parallelStream and lambdas, but did not find how to implement this particular situation.

Here is a solution using streams and lambdas:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> strings = getStrings();

    Pair<Integer, Integer> sum = strings.stream()
                .parallel()
                .map(Main::getPair)
                .reduce(Main::sum)
                .get();

}

private static Pair<Integer, Integer> getPair(String str) {
    // do some work and return pair
    return new Pair<>(1, 1);
}

private static Pair<Integer, Integer> sum(Pair<Integer, Integer> a, Pair<Integer, Integer> b) {
        return new Pair<>(
                a.getKey() + b.getKey(),
                a.getValue() + b.getValue());
}
```

However, this will throw an exception in the main thread as soon as one of the invocations throws one. You could return a pair containing zeros if one fails though so it will not affect the result.